# how to use "wait for pattern" when recording MobaXterm macros?

Tags: mobaxterm

How to use "wait for pattern" when recording MobaXterm macros?  Is there a manual for "wait for pattern"? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is meant to be used to wait (pause macro execution) until it encounters a specific phrase.

For example, I build a app, then copy it over to a device via SSH which requires a password. Since building my app isn't a constant time, I included the "wait for a pattern" command which waits until it sees the phrase "password:", at which point it then continues on with the macro.

From what I can tell (I'm still fairly new myself to Xterm), the "wait for a pattern" pauses the macro until it sees a specific phrase appear in your terminal, at which point the macro will then continue running.

As far as I know, I don't see a manual for this, though I haven't looked all that hard.

Comment: thanks。I know now how to use "wait for pattern". for example: select "wait for pattern", and then enter "ftp", the macro will run when the screan outputs "ftp>".

Answer (score 0):

The "Wait for pattern" construct in MobaXterm macros is most likely an implementation of the "expect" keyword in the Linux "expect" utility.

Please see

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/exploring-expect/9781565920903/ch01.html

which gives examples and which explains...

"Expect is named after the specific command that waits for output from a program. The expect command is the heart of the Expect program. The expect command describes a list of patterns to watch for. Each pattern is followed by an action. If the pattern is found, the action is executed."

In the MobaXterm context, I think that "Wait for pattern" has nothing todo with waiting for a specified time period.  Instead, it instructs the macro to look at text that is appearing on the console (as a result of prior instructions in your macro) and to *scan for* ("wait for") a particular string, proceeding with subsequent instructions only once the string is seen.  This prevents your macro from "answering" prompts that haven't yet appeared on the screen.  It's used to coordinate the timing of p